# Best Practice to fix Stud Wall Distance Between 2 Walls?

Tags: studs, basement-refinishing

I'm needing some assistance as im doing the stud walls myself on what the *best* way to fix this issue in the diagram is? Basically i did the stud walls for the pink line, and i have a laser line that prior to installing the stud walls measured the same distance from the orange and red line. Now that i have installed there's a 0.5" difference and since i have no experience im not sure if that will be "noticeable" when we complete it.

With all that said i think there's 2 options to consider it would be fantastic to know what a normal builder would do in this situation. (especially because the blue wall is yet to be built)

Option 1.) Leave the measurement as is and line up the studs based on the 0.5" difference it wont be noticeable

Option 2.) Take the smallest measurement (77" and measure that distance on the red, orange, and yellow so the HVAC box that is built around in the ceiling is straight the entire way across).

My primary concern with option 1 is that with the box around the HVAC vents in the ceiling i dont want someone to look at that and all the way down the wall and "notice" the 0.5" difference.

[image: basement_measurement_diagram]

Real picture from the yellow wall:
[image]

Thanks for any comments and help!

Comment: It probably will not be that noticeable once it is finished, instead of 90 degree corners, they might be 88 or 92 degrees.  All finishing will need to be measured three times to make sure the little extra is accounted for.  Would fix now a tiny bit, than make extra work after.

Comment: No one will notice. My 1902 house has larger variations and you'd never know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter, but on the basis of "can't be unseen"  you'll feel better for correcting it.

If you want the walls to be the same length you can notch the top and bottom plates where the long wall is and install the end stud sideways.

Comment: Thanks Jasen. will just measure and re-do!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to double up the drywall on the ends of the orange and yellow walls.

When you're applying your drywall to finish this, your red wall will end up measuring 78" (assuming 1/2" drywall). Adding a single layer of drywall to the end of the orange and yellow walls will bump them out the 77.5" - potentially noticeable. Adding a *second* layer of 1/2" drywall will make them 78" just like the red wall, and presto! the difference vanishes.